# Ethereum Smart Contracts/dApp’s open source license?

Tags: solidity, legal

Can a smart contract in which it’s source was released be GPLv3/GNU licensed? I.e. if a company were to release the source code to a smart contract, can that smart contracts source code be GPLv3/GNU licensed?